# HeidiSQL 10.2 with Postgres doesnt show newly created database

Tags: postgresql, heidisql

I connected PostgreSQL to heidiSQL and each time I create a new Database, it does not appear in the database list, even after refreshing or restarting Heidi.

If I try to create it back, it tells me that the database already exists.

I really don't know what to do by now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you told your session to display only one or some of all databases:

[image]

Remove these, or add the newly created database there to let HeidiSQL display it.